# What does ':' (colon) do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and while browsing through the jQuery library I see `:` (colon) being used a lot. What is this used for in JavaScript?

```
// Return an array of filtered elements (r)
// and the modified expression string (t)
   return { r: r, t: t };
```

Answer (score 272, accepted):

```
var o = {
    r: 'some value',
    t: 'some other value'
};
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
var o = new Object();
o.r = 'some value';
o.t = 'some other value';
```

Comment: So similar to C# object initializer syntax. Thanks!

Comment: What if there is no enclosing object?

Comment: @FranciscI.B if i had to guess, i think that's TypeScript, which is a superset of JavaScript. It's declaring a class, with a var named xMin, whose type is a float. Pretty sur that's what that means.

Answer (score 113):

And also, a colon can be used to label a statement. for example

```
var i = 100, j = 100;
outerloop:
while(i>0) {
  while(j>0) {
   j++

   if(j>50) {
     break outerloop;
   }
  }
i++

}
```

Comment: A goto cannot be disguised: you simply break goto; and you've found it! ;)

Comment: MDN Reference page for JS Label:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: yep, that's why a=>{b:2} will not throw and return undefined

Answer (score 82):

You guys are forgetting that the colon is also used in the ternary operator (though I don't know if jquery uses it for this purpose).

the ternary operator is an expression form (expressions return a value) of an if/then statement. it's used like this:

```
var result = (condition) ? (value1) : (value2) ;
```

A ternary operator could also be used to produce side effects just like if/then, but this is profoundly bad practice.

Comment: AKA "ternary operator". Note that the OP is strictly asking about the object literal case. If we're to go even beyond what the OP is asking, the colon is also used in labels.

Comment: yes I did mean that. I should just stay off the internet, really, if i'm going to go around flagrantly mis-identifying programming concepts like that.

Comment: It would be awesome to see it used for labels and whatever else so the use is never confused @AtesGoral because I am now still googling those right now.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to list the things that : isn't used for in Javascript.

Answer (score 49):

The ':' is a delimiter for key value pairs basically. In your example it is a Javascript Object Literal notation.

In javascript, Objects are defined with the colon delimiting the identifier for the property, and its value so you can have the following:

```
return { 
    Property1 : 125,
    Property2 : "something",
    Method1 : function() { /* do nothing */ },
    array: [5, 3, 6, 7]
};
```

and then use it like:

```
var o =  { 
    property1 : 125,
    property2 : "something",
    method1 : function() { /* do nothing */ },
    array: [5, 3, 6, 7]
};

alert(o.property1); // Will display "125"
```

A subset of this is also known as JSON (Javascript Object Notation) which is useful in AJAX calls because it is compact and quick to parse in server-side languages and Javascript can easily de-serialize a JSON string into an object.

```
// The parenthesis '(' & ')' around the object are important here
var o = eval('(' + "{key: \"value\"}" + ')');
```

You can also put the key inside quotes if it contains some sort of special character or spaces, but I wouldn't recommend that because it just makes things harder to work with.

Keep in mind that [JavaScript Object *Literal* Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals) in the JavaScript language is different from the JSON standard for message passing. The main difference between the 2 is that functions and constructors are not part of the [JSON standard](http://json.org/), but are allowed in JS object literals.

Comment: As I read your response I thought I would vote it up, but then you said that "It is also known as JSON". Object literals and JSON are definitely *not* the same thing, indeed your examples before you mention JSON are not valid JSON.

Comment: @nnnnnn The difference between the 2 are very subtle, but important nonetheless. I've updated my answer to be more specific in regards to that.

Comment: I see the update. Nice. Note that JSON *requires* that key names be in quotes.

Comment: Why do you have to mention all of that twice? When you said "and then use it like"

Answer (score 19):

It is part of the object literal syntax. The basic format is:

```
var obj = { field_name: "field value", other_field: 42 };
```

Then you can access these values with:

```
obj.field_name; // -> "field value"
obj["field_name"]; // -> "field value"
```

You can even have functions as values, basically giving you the methods of the object:

```
obj['func'] = function(a) { return 5 + a;};
obj.func(4);  // -> 9
```

Comment: Great because it gave me the term to search for and find out more information.

Answer (score 15):

These are generally the scenarios where colon ':' is used in JavaScript

1- Declaring and Initializing an Object

```
var Car = {model:"2015", color:"blue"}; //car object with model and color properties
```

2- Setting a Label (Not recommended since it results in complicated control structure and Spaghetti code)

```
List: 
while(counter < 50)
{
     userInput += userInput;
     counter++;
     if(userInput > 10000)
     {
          break List;
     }
}
```

3- In Switch Statement

```
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 6:
        text = "Today is Saturday";
        break; 
    case 0:
        text = "Today is Sunday";
        break; 
    default: 
        text = "Looking forward to the Weekend";
}
```

4- In Ternary Operator

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = age>18? "True" : "False";
```

Comment: A single colon can also be used for short-circuit evaluation in lieu of `||`.

Example:
`var a = false, b = a || 'Default value';`
is equivalent to
`var a = false, b = a : 'Default value';`

Answer (score 14):

It can be used to list objects in a variable. Also, it is used a little bit in the shorthand of an if sentence:

```
var something = {face: 'hello',man: 'hey',go: 'sup'};
```

And calling it like this

```
alert(something.man);
```

Also the if sentence:

```
function something() {  
  (some) ? doathing() : dostuff(); // if some = true doathing();, else dostuff();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Let's not forget the switch statement, where colon is used after each "case".

Answer (score 10):

Another usage of colon in JavaScript is to rename a variable, that is:

```
const person = { 
    nickNameThatIUseOnStackOverflow: "schlingel",
    age: 30,
    firstName: "John"
};
let { nickNameThatIUseOnStackOverflow: nick } = person; // I take nickNameThatIUseOnStackOverflow but want to refer it as "nick" from now on.
nick = "schling";
```

This is useful if you use a third party library that returns values having awkward / long variable names that you want to rename in your code.

Comment: Wow! How do you even know this?

Comment: @Saptadeep I have seen some usages of it, I guess.

Answer (score 8):

That's JSON, or JavaScript Object Notation. It's a quick way of describing an object, or a hash map. The thing before the colon is the property name, and the thing after the colon is its value. So in this example, there's a property "r", whose value is whatever's in the variable r. Same for t.

Comment: JSON is only a subset of JavaScript object initialization syntax. '{ a: k() }' where k is a function is not JSON, but it is perfectly fine JavaScript object initialization syntax.

Comment: To be pedantic, no, it's not "JSON". It _looks_ like JSON. It's the object literal syntax that is native to JavaScript and that can appear directly inside code. JSON on the other hand is a data serialization/interchange format. JSON is JSON only when it's "airborne", i.e. in transit or when it's not yet parsed into a real object.

Comment: +1 for Ates Goral, but note that the example given doesn't even *look* like JSON: the names would have to be in double-quotes for it to be valid JSON syntax.

Answer (score 5):

One stupid mistake I did awhile ago that might help some people.

Keep in mind that if you are using ":" in an event like this, the value will not change

```
var ondrag = (function(event, ui) {
            ...

            nub0x: event.target.offsetLeft + event.target.clientWidth/2;
            nub0y = event.target.offsetTop + event.target.clientHeight/2;

            ...
        });
```

So "nub0x" will initialize with the first event that happens and will never change its value. But "nub0y" will change during the next events.

Comment: I came upon this, and fyi actually what is happening here is that you are using a label before your statement. No assignment is made, but the statement `event.target.offsetLeft + event.target.clientWidth/2;` does run each time your ondrag method is called, but never assign the value to `nub0x`

Comment: Actually this is being used as an evaluation, and the `:` is being treated as though it were a `||`. Therefore, `event.target.offsetLeft + event.target.clientWidth/2;` will only trigger each time provided `nub0x` equates to false.