# Why is this valid code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/idazeg/edit#javascript,html

Can someone tell me how and **why** this is working?

```
$('#pp').click (function () {
    ppp:doSomething('2'); //<=== ppp , how is JS **eating** this ?
});
```

Comment: It may be clearer if you explain what you *expect* this to do, and what it *actually* does.  (People might be able to work that out from the context, but I'm not one of them.)

Comment: I expect to understand the `ppp:` role here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-do-in-javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ppp:` is a [label statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).  It's syntactically equivalent to:

```
ppp:
doSomething('2');
```

It's mostly useless here, most devs reserve them for allowing greater control over nested loops:

```
loop1:
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
      if (i == 1 && j == 1) {
         continue loop1;
      } else {
         console.log("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in the above case the `ppp:` just works as a label. So there would be no difference if you remove it and only use `doSomething('2');`