# Why isn't string getting passed into function - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, I grab HTML using jQuery's $.ajax function.

In the success function I alert it (this works correctly and shows an HTML string as expected);

Then I pass it in as a variable to another function, processHTML. But it's not working and says the variable is null. I confirm this with an alert.

```
var my = my || {};

jQuery(function ($) {
  my.html = {
    getHTML: function(url) {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function( myHTML ) {
          alert(myHTML); // shows string, as expected
          my.html.processHTML(myHTML); //returns null
        }
       });
    },

    processHTML: function ( myHTML ) {
      alert(myHTML);
      // do stuff and return myHTML
    }

  } // end of my.html object
}); // end of jQuery wrapper function
```

Why isn't the string getting passed from the success callback into the processHTML function? If I replace myHTML in the success callback with an actual string (`<div>test</div>`), that gets successfully passed into the function.

---

**Update:** Here's the actual code, as requested.  It is invoked by clicking a link with `onclick="hey.mydoc.ajax2({source: 'http://www.mysite.com/mypage'})"`. This is also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/WMSZk/) but I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hey` when clicking the link, which doesn't happen on my site.

```
var hey = hey || {};

jQuery(function ($) {

hey.mydoc = {

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        getHTML: function ( source ) {

                  $.ajax({
                      url: source,
                      dataType: "html",
                      beforeSend: function(){ 
                        },
                      success: function( myHTML ) {
                        alert('myHTML is '+myHTML );
                        hey.mydoc.processHTML( myHTML );
                      } // end of success function
                  });
        }, // end of method


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        processHTML: function ( myHTML ) {

        alert ('processHTML - ' + myHTML );
             myHTML = $(myHTML);
            myHTML.find('script').remove();
            // and a bunch of other DOM manipulations...

           var content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>" +  myHTML.html() + "</html>";
           return content;
        }, // end of method


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ajax2: function ( options ){


        $.ajax({
                  url: options.content,
                  dataType: "html",
                  success: function( myHTML ) {
                    alert('myHTML is '+myHTML ); // myHTML is string of html, as expected
                    var newHTML = hey.mydoc.processHTML( myHTML );  // myHTML not getting passed in
                    alert(newHTML);

                  } // end of success function
              });
        } // end of method
   } // end of hey.mydoc namespace


}); //end of jQuery wrapper
```

Comment: Please post the actual code that is giving you trouble. This looks like a trimmed down example to me.

Comment: Is this your actual code? `var getHTML: function(url)` will fail right away with `Unexpected token :` error.

Comment: Is this your exact javascript code or parts you copy-pasted here ? Syntax seems odd as it is using `:` and `=` to define the functions. Do you get any error messages in the console ?

Comment: Change the order. Move the var processHTML above the ajax call.

Comment: @j08691: That shouldn't make any difference. The AJAX call is asynchronous, so the `processHTML` assignment will happen before the callback happens.

Comment: @amnotiam: It shouldn't, but it did when I tested it.

Comment: @j08691: Do you have a jsFiddle of that test? In a single threaded environment, the asynchronous code must allow the rest of the synchronous code to finish before it executes.

Comment: @supertrue: What does `alert(myHTML)` inside `processHTML` method alert?

Comment: @supertrue: You still haven't shown anything that would demonstrate an issue, and it's still an incomplete example. For example we don't see where `getHTML` is being called. Please post your actual code.

Comment: @amnotiam updated with code and jsfiddle.

Comment: @supertrue: Your `hey` won't be seen by the `onclick` because you've chosen `onLoad` from the left menu. Change it to `no wrap (body)`. Aside from that, there's no issue to be seen here,

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
function processHTML(myHTML) {
    alert(myHTML);
    // do stuff and return myHTML
}
```

Comment: The incorrect/inconsistent function definitions were typos from condensing the code. I've now posted the full code and jsfiddle above, if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think a friend of mine had the same problem last weekend.

I tolled him he'd better use deferreds http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

```
$.ajax({ object literal except success attribute }).success(function() {..
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to pass the parameter.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/something/some.do",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: completeCallback,
        contentType: "text/html; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}

function completeCallback(myHTML) {
    alert(myHTML)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this - remove the '=' (equal sign) after processHTML and put a colon.

Comment: That isn't correct. Variable assignment requires `=`, not `:`.

Comment: The variable getHTML is being assigned with a colon.

Comment: Just for `:` reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-do-in-javascript

Comment: @PhillipKregg: I know, and that's incorrect. Though it's probably just a typo in the question since OP stated that replacing `processHTML(myHTML)` with `processHTML('<div>test</div>')` works, so we know it isn't a *SyntaxError*

Comment: Ok, my bad - I saw the difference in syntax and responded before the OP posted that the <div>test</div> worked.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: I updated the code to show that it's in an namespacey sort of object. Those were just typos made in trimming down the example code.

Comment: @PhillipKregg: I just updated to show the actual code and a jsfiddle. Any ideas?