# Colon within a Javascript function while loop

Tags: javascript, html

I was poking around some HTML5 Javascript demos and came across something I've never seen before in the syntax. Take a look at the run function and notice how the **search** object notation is made in the **while loop**. Lines of interest include 15 and 18. Can anyone explain this syntax?

```
function run() {
  var n = 1;
  search: while (running) {
    n += 1;
    for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 1)
      if (n % i == 0)
       continue search;
    // found a prime!
    postMessage(n);
  }
}
```

(code taken from here; http://html5demos.com/js/cruncher.js)

Comment: Here you go
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-do-in-javascript

Useth thy Google and thou shalt find!

Comment: @limelights that post is about the more common use for the colon, which doesn't happen to be the case here

Comment: the % in line 18 is a modulus

Comment: Although reading the entire post it'll be revealed that the ":" operator is also a label for something, I thought it would kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: i honestly didn't know javascript had labels like this. i am kind of glad i didn't...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not object (literal) notation, it is [defining a `label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

A `label` can be used to give a looping construct a name. The benefits of doing this is that you can create more powerful `breaks;` or `continues;` by referencing outer loops (by their labels).

**Note** that how the structure of the program you referenced is a:

```
search: while () {
   for (;;;) {

   }
}
```

... and the author is using `continue search;` *inside the `for` loop* to continue the execution of the while loop.

As for what's happening on line 18, `if (n % i == 0)` is using the [modulo (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_%28Modulus%29) to get the remainder between dividing `n / i`, and checking whether it's 0.

Comment: Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 3):

`search:` is a label in this case that you can use to refer to this loop.

For example you can break this loop by doing `break search;`

Answer (score 1):

Since no one answered **both** your questions.

`search: while`, here `search` is a label which helps uniquely identify the while loop, which as mentioned, helps when using `break` and/or `continue` within nested loops.

Line 18 `(n % i ===0)`

Is basically looking for an odd number by applying the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a label, mainly used in nested loops to break/continue a certain loop that is marked by this label. This is a standard in every programming language and not javascript specific. Read more here in section "Using Labels to Control the Flow"

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_loop_control.htm