# What does ":" do in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ':' do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-do-in-javascript)

I'm trying to learn jQuery and I noticed the following syntax in someone's code. It would be great if some one can explain it to me.

```
functionName: function(form, callback)
    {   
        form.submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            callback(TestPageUtils.getFormParams(form));
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Back to the basics. I suggest you start with JavaScript, and then go to jQuery, a whole different world!

Comment: @user1558274 - Actually, jQuery is a perfectly appropriate place to start.  It's a great way to just "get stuff done" (by not having to dwell on low level details and/or reinvent the wheel), studying jQuery is also a great way to learn "good style".  I think you're doing the right thing.  IMHO...

Answer (score 9):

The syntax `{ property: value }` is standard JavaScript notation.

At the left hand of your colon is the property name, in your case "functionName", at the right hand is its value, in your case a function definition.

These functions, then, are comma separated:

```
var obj = { x: 1, f: function(a) { alert(a); } };

alert(obj.x) // alerts 1
obj.f(1)     // alerts 1
```

Answer (score 2):

That's "not" jQuery, but general Javascript syntax. And that is how you define a member inside an object literal, in this case, that member is a function.

For example:

```
person = 
{
    name: "John",
    age: 432,
    walk: function (){alert("Walking!");}
}
```

Is another Javascript object. To access its members, simply do `person.name`. Or, if you want the person to walk, call its walk method like this: `person.walk()`.

Answer (score 0):

that's not "jQuery" per se - it's basic Javascript syntax.

The ":" says the property "functionName" has the value `function(...) { ... }`

Here's a good diagram (the same construct is often used in JSON syntax):

http://www.json.org/