# Variables declared with ":" instead of "="

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Can someone explain the difference in Javascript between:

```
var x = something
```

and

```
var x : something
```

I have no idea on where/how to search about it.

I saw the code above at the bottom of page 4 of this document: http://download.unity3d.com/support/Tutorials/2%20-%20Scripting%20Tutorial.pdf

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are referring to object properties, yes?

Comment: See here: [What does ':' do in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/418799/102937)

Comment: nope, see here page 4 of this document, at the bottom.
http://download.unity3d.com/support/Tutorials/2%20-%20Scripting%20Tutorial.pdf

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed. I still don't understand why 'var x : something' seems to work and what exactly it does. The link provided doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Your question was closed because your question has already been asked and answers on Stack Overflow. Look at the very top of your question and you'll see the link to the question you duplicated.

Comment: @mah: unfortunately this question isn’t actually a duplicate of the suggested duplicate question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first one assigns something to a variable x and the other causes a syntax error.

You're probably mixing up assigning a property in an object literal and normal assignment.

```
var x = something;//assigning a variable
var y = {
    x:something//assigning a object property
};
```

Edit

```
var target : Transform;
```

seems to be [UnityScript not JavaScript](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript), it looks like it is not assigning a value but rather setting the variable type. see [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript#Dynamic_typing_is_inefficient)

Comment: page 4, at the bottom http://download.unity3d.com/support/Tutorials/2%20-%20Scripting%20Tutorial.pdf

Comment: so Unity uses a more sophisticated JavaScript? My bad, I should have told it was about Unity but I was thinking that was just plain JS. Thanks!

Comment: Dammit! I'm using JavaScript just to stay away from variables types declaration and then I discover this. Dang. Thanks a lot for the link! Now I understand.

Answer (score 3):

UnityScript is not JavaScript

[Unity Script vs Javascript](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

If you're defining vars in an object, you'd use colons.

```
var obj = {x:my_var};
```