# Difference between this.property and property with colon

Tags: javascript, this

I'm making a LinkedList class:

```
function LinkedList(){
           ...
```

What is the difference between:

```
this.addNode = function(data){
           ...
```

and

```
addNode: function(data){
           ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ':' (colon) do in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript)

Comment: https://blog.jcoglan.com/2007/07/23/writing-a-linked-list-in-javascript/ lol are you doing homework?

Answer (score 2):

This creates a property on an object (assuming `this` references an object)

```
this.addNode = function(data) { ...
```

That's an assignment expression, and if it's all by itself then it comprises a statement.

This, on the other hand, is part of an **object literal** expression:

```
addNode: function(data) { ...
```

It only makes sense inside an object literal, which looks like:

```
var someObject = {
  property1: value1,
  property2: value2,
  // ...
};
```

In a larger sense, it doesn't make a lot of sense to compare the two; they're two different ways of doing the same thing, in a way, but they make sense in disjoint contexts. The first is a way of adding or resetting a property on an existing object, while the second is a way of setting a property as part of the creation of a new object.