# What does `image: HTMLImageElement` do?

Tags: javascript

I tried writing `image: HTMLImageElement` in my browser console today. I expected an error would occur, but it didn't.

This does not declare a variable as `var image: HTMLImageElement` on TypeScript does, and it also does not define a property as `var x = { image: HTMLImageElement }` does. It seems that this actually does nothing. What does this syntax do?

Comment: You just created a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) called `image`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ':' (colon) do in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript) ([this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/418865/660921))

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that JavaScript also has labels! Thank you for everyone. I have searched and found that post, but it seems I scrolled the page down too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless within an object, text followed by a colon in JavaScript is a [*labelled statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). An example labelled statement which you will have probably seen before is:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)">
```

In this case, `javascript` is the label and `void(0)` is the statement. In your case, `image` is the label and `HTMLImageElement` is the statement.