# How : operator works in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why next code doesn't occur errors?

```
var bar = 1,
    foo = {};

foo: {
    bar: 2;
    baz: ++bar;
};
```

It returns `2`

It known that javascript has labels, it helps to manage loops and if-statements. 
Could this code be useful?
I saw that AngularJS framework  with `::` operator provide one-time binding.  Maybe do you hear some another example of using that strange operator.

Comment: See this question: [What does colon do in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript)

Comment: @doldt: That's a similar-looking but entirely different use of colons.

Comment: `foo: {
    bar: 2;
    baz: ++bar;
};` must be `foo: {
    bar: 2,
    baz: ++bar
};` you're using `;` instead of  `,`

Comment: @mohamedrias: No, the code is correct as given. That's not an object literal; it's a block statement with labels inside that just looks a lot like an object literal.

Comment: @user2357112 The answers in that link explain the label use-case of colons, which is in effect here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an error because the `foo` in `foo: {...}` is a [statement label](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12). It has nothing to do with your `foo` variable, and it has nothing to do with assigning anything to anything.

Similarly, the `{` and `}` define a block, not an object, and the `bar` and `baz` inside are also statement labels.

The statements

```
2;
```

and

```
++bar;
```

are perfectly valid. The first looks a bit odd, but it's valid; in JavaScript, any expression [can be used as a statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4), including a simple constant. (Which is useful; it's how JavaScript slipped in the `"use strict"` directive.)

The result is `2` because the block [takes the value of the last statement in the block](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1), which is `++bar;`.

Unless something is using those statement labels, that code is equivalent to:

```
var bar = 1,
    foo = {};

2;
++bar;
```

> Could this code be useful?

Purely as given, I don't see how, no. But note that if you had a loop inside the `foo` block, and you had something after the loop, you could use a directed break to jump past the thing after the loop:

```js
var bar = 1,
  foo = {};

foo: {
  bar: 2;
  baz: ++bar;
  for (var n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    snippet.log("n = " + n);
    if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
      break foo;
    }
  }
  snippet.log("Probably don't get here");
};
snippet.log("Done");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

There, you won't see `Probably don't get here` except in the outlying case where `Math.random()` returned a value less than `0.3` ten times in a row.

You need a loop or a `switch` in order to do that, though; [`break` is only valid in loops and `switch`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.8). And it would be a **very** unusual thing to do...

Comment: And the `++bar;` evaluates to 2, which is then what the containing block `{ }` evaluates to, (i.e. it's last statement.), which is why it returns `2`.

Comment: @SamHasler: Thanks! I'd missed that part of the question, and I didn't know that about blocks until I went and looked it up. :-)