# What happens if we define a property inside a function using : operator?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I added a new property to the function obj1. However, when I print the value of obj1.name, it shows nothing, just blank!

Well, if what I am doing is wrong then the JavaScript engine has to complain, but it does not. So what is going on here?

```
var obj1 = function (){
    name:"john";
};


console.log(obj1.name);// prints nothing!
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/418865/344643

Comment: here are the errors I get when I pasted your code:  
`Line 2: Label 'name' on john statement.`
`Line 2: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.`

Comment: link to code: https://jsbin.com/caneso/2/edit?js,console

Comment: I just pasted it in a JSBin, same thing on jshint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name:` token here is parsed as a label.

So it's a syntactically valid script that:

1. declares a label
2. evaluates a string expression

So, `obj1.name` is still undefined since you haven't set its properties anywhere.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label