# Colon in JavaScript statement

Tags: javascript

The following code is extracted from SharePoint's SP.UserProfiles.debug.js library.

```
    getUserProfilePropertiesFor: function (d) {
    a: ;
    var b = this.get_context(),
    a,
    c = new SP.ClientActionInvokeMethod(this, "GetUserProfilePropertiesFor", [d]);
    b.addQuery(c);
    a = [];
    b.addQueryIdAndResultObject(c.get_id(), a);
    return a
}
```

What does the "a: ;" on second line mean? When I step-through in IE Developer tool, that line was skipped right through. But it also does not look like a label as it has a semi-colon at the end.

Comment: Huh, I'd never seen this before, but apparently it can be [used to label a statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript#418865)...  Here's some more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: Why would a semi-colon mean that it was not a label? It's a label on an empty statement.

Comment: @torazaburo He probably meant "variable"

Comment: At first I thought it was minified code and some kind of marker for the minification. But then I saw it came from a file ending in `*.debug.js` and was horrified to think that was unminified code! Dear gods tell me they don't actually code their variable names like that!

Comment: @Sukima, that's SharePoint out of box JavaScript library.

Comment: That is some terrible code - maybe some tool generated it?

Comment: I've never used labels in JavaScript before and today it's the first time I see something like this, I did Google a bit and see the possibility that can be a label. But nowhere in that little function require the use of that label, plus a few more lines later there is a = [];. Also this is just one of the many functions in that script library that has this kind of code. So I thought maybe it's something other than a label. Besides, all the JavaScript label example I've found uses label to break out loops. I don't see why there should need a label in this function.

Comment: @John Hascall, yes it does look ugly. But I don't think they expect SharePoint users (even developers) to dig out their code. Generally people uses MSDN to find the methods they can use. I just opened this file out of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does the "a: ;" on second line mean?

It is a label statement : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label