# What does the colon mean in this JavaScript snippet (not an object literal)?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I apologize for posting a duplicate-looking question, (I know, that there is a bunch of similar titled questions here), but none of the questions already present seems to suit my case.

In short, what does the colon do here:

```
<script>
  'use strict';
  foo: 1;

  //whatever else
</script>
```

I supposed this to be a syntax error, but it's not. And it's not a label, I think, since adding a line `break foo;` throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'foo'` (though [a doc page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript) suggests exactly this, that it's a label).

I suppose this is some recent addition to the JavaScript syntax, since I have never heard of such use of the colon.

---

If anyone wonders, why I'm asking this, this is my explanation: I was reading [an MDN doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals) and there is an example:

```
var func = () => { foo: 1 };               
// Calling func() returns undefined!
```

It shows, that the curly braces in this case are treated as block delimiters and not an object literal. So I supposed, that somehow `foo: 1` on its own must be  syntactically legal. And indeed it is.

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript), which is supposed to cover every use of the colon in JavaScript, but it doesn't mention this, and no answer there does this either.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a label. I suspect you're getting that error with `break foo;` because `foo` isn't a loop you can break from.

Comment: Why the downvote? A guy doesn't know arrow function, he tried understanding, asked a clean question and got a clear answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd have read further down the page you linked, you would see why it was written like that.

```
var func = () => { foo: 1 };
```

This is an attempt to return an object from a arrow function.

That doesn't work for reasons explained here:

> *This is because the code inside braces (`{}`) is parsed as a sequence of statements (i.e. `foo` is treated like a label, not a key in an object literal). ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals))*

So the returned value needs to be wrapped in parentheses:

```
var func = () => ({foo: 1});
```

---

To actually answer your question:

## It's a label.

You can't just take the `foo: 1` out of context like that.

Comment: I actually read it further though after I posted the question. Yes probably it's a label, because Firefox doesn't throw on it. Probably it is just some Chrome specific issue.

Comment: _"Yes probably it's a label"_ No, not "probably". It _is_ a label. ;-) This isn't an "issue". This is working as expected.

Comment: by the "issue" I meant, that Chrome probably shouldn't throw on this, if it is a legal syntax

Comment: You mean it throws on the `break foo` line?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, Firefox throws on this either `SyntaxError: label not found`

Comment: yes, I meant this, that it throws on the `break foo` line and it seems illogical, at least just the error message itself. If the foo: 1 was treated like a label, so why the message is "label not found" or similar

Comment: sorry, I understood now, that the `break` statement is definitely expected to search for a label inside a loop or one of parent loops. So the message is also completely logical

Comment: Because the label is pointing at a single digit, `1`, which makes no sense. This, on the other hand, is fine:  `foo:for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){break foo}`