# Javascript colon (:) operator inside function

Tags: javascript

I apologize if this question is stupid or duplicated, please point me to the right direction if so.

I've tested this code:

```
function b()
{
    a: 22;
    return a;
}
```

Code returns no error. Which leads me into thinking `a: 20` inside function works. Though when call the function:

```
b();
```

..I receive "ReferenceError: a is not defined"

What does `a: 22` inside function actually do? `this.a` inside function returns nothing so I don't think it has something to do with function as object (or it does?..)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does ':' (colon) do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418799/what-does-colon-do-in-javascript)

Comment: `a: 22` is a label: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: @0stone0 unfortunately no

Comment: @DanielDiekmeier never heard of labels in javascript. Thanks! Do post as answer to mark it

Comment: @user8555937 yes the second one with 93 ups actually answers your question

Comment: @user8555937 Please take a look at the [second aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418865/5625547) which explains the `label` style as @Daniel explains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a: 22` in your code is a label – it labels the statement `22` with the identifier `a`.

From MDN:

> The labeled statement can be used with break or continue statements. It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label